# Flutter Function gets called on all buttons at once

Tags: function, flutter, button, callback

When I am pressing a button, for some reason all buttons are pressed (functions gets excetuded on all buttons). I am sure that the answer is something silly, but I have spent so many hours trying to figure it out.
Please be so kind and help me :)

```
class _QuizCardState extends State<QuizCard> {
  Color colorToShow = transColor;
  Color right = orangeColor;
  Color wrong = redColor;
  Color btnColor;
  Color tabTextColor = blueColor;
  int marks = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return FutureBuilder(
      future:
          DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/questions.json"),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        List questions = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());

        void checkAnswer() {
          if (questions[2]["1"] == questions[1]["1"]['c']) {
            marks = marks + 1;
            colorToShow = right;
            tabTextColor = Colors.white;
        
          } else {
            colorToShow = wrong;
            tabTextColor = Colors.white;
          }
          // setState(() {});
        }
```

And then the functions is passed over via the constructor to the button:

```
 AnswerTab(
    questions[1]["1"]['a'],
    checkAnswer,
    tabTextColor,
    colorToShow),
AnswerTab(
    questions[1]["1"]['a'],
    checkAnswer,
    tabTextColor,
    colorToShow),
```

And in the button widget is it excecuted like this:

```
class AnswerTab extends StatelessWidget {
  final String tabText;
  final Function checkAnswer;
  final Color textColor;
  final Color bgColor;

  AnswerTab(this.tabText, this.checkAnswer, this.textColor, this.bgColor);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: checkAnswer,
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Using class for buttons and passing  information to it makes it triggering of all buttons at same time on tapping. To resolve this i suggest to  write code for each button separately in same class do not use class for buttons or else you have to do something for differentiating buttons from one another .

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But isn't there a possibility that the function that is passed in the button class is only called at the specific button pressed? The other buttons that will not be pressed should not change their default behaviour. I think this should be possible. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can't really say without seeing more of the code, since I am not so sure what you are trying to achieve.
But what does seem suspicious to me is your `List questions`, since you are comparing `questions[2]["1"] == questions[1]["1"]['c']` It seems to me like you might be missing something in your comparison

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Ineed I am. The comparissons are just a test and not the full logic of it. But this is not currently my problem but the thing that if I press one button every other button gets pressed even if its not included in the comparisons.